# jquery parent sibling usage

Tags: jquery, html

I have a xhtml page with the following structure

```
<h:panelGroup >
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="a1" class=value />
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup >
    <h:inputText id="a2" class= amt/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

I am using a jquery to call a popup box when there is BLUR event in the input box and the BooleanCheckbox is checked. 
I am using the following jquery statement to access the BooleanCheckbox from input text box.

```
jQuery(this).parent().siblings().find(".value");
```

However its not giving me the results. Can you suggest the proper parent sibling realation.

Comment: You need to view the output/runtime HTML and see what a panelGroup spits out. It may be more than one ancestor. Chrome's F12 DOM inspector is great for that sort of thing.

Comment: you can use jQuery(this).parent().siblings('.value')

Comment: @Shubham Nigam: No you can't as .value is a child of the parent siblings, not a sibling.

Comment: This is not XHTML, this is some other XML thing. In XML, `class` has no special meaning. This also means, that jQuery won't find elements by their class.

Comment: Boldewyn, the same code is working fine at other places. An d yes, it's a xhtml file only.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) you can go to the previous sibling. Something like this should do

```
jQuery(this).parent().prev().find('.value')  
// refers to the checkbox and NOT the value
```

The above works for the XHTML structure given in the question.

However, OP had a structure different from the one in the question and ended up using (check comments)

```
jQuery(this).parent().parent().prev().children().children()
```

Comment: are you sure `this` refers to the input ?

Comment: I was basing my suggestion on this example: http://jsbin.com/qamedo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: the example seems to be be right, but in my project it's not working.

Comment: I would suggest a step by step debugging. What does `.parent()` point to and then what does `.prev()` point to ?

Comment: Hi Dhiraj, it's pointing to correct parent, but for .prev() its showing "undefined" value.

Comment: can you please confirm that the structure in the question is same as in your project. Because I don't understand why it wouldn't work

Comment: hi Dhiraj, yes the structure is exactly the same.

Comment: Hi Dhiraj, there was some problem with the structure itself. this is the final code that worked. "jQuery(this).parent().parent().prev().children().children" for me. Thanks for the brainstorming.

Comment: you can replace `parent().parent()` with `parents(selector)` and `children().children()` with just `find()` because `find` will go through the children

Comment: @downvoter: Please consider explaining when doing a downvote

Comment: @downvoter: I agree with Dhiraj, his questioning helped me solve the issue.